# Deriving an Input Value in an Algebra Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working out an algebra problem and am wondering if it is possible to isolate the "Input" value below:

**Input / (Input + Constant A) = Constant B**

I've tried adjusting it, but have only gotten to:

**Input - (Input * Constant B) = (Constant A * Constant B)**

I can't seem to get the "input" value by itself, and I am wondering if it is even possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: this is just a linear equation. The left hand side is $I(1-B)$

Answer (score 2):

So you start with $\frac{I}{I+A}=B$.  Multiply by $(I+A)$ to get 
$$
I = B(I+A) 
$$
Distribute
$$
I=IB+AB
$$
Subtract $IB$
$$
I-IB=AB
$$
Factor out I
$$
I(1-B)=AB
$$
Divide by $(1-B)$
$$
I=\frac{AB}{1-B}
$$

Comment: Thank You!  Exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

Let me rewrite this because "input" and "constant" are quite long.

Your initial equation is $\frac{x}{x+a} = b.$ Note that if $b = 1$, this would mean that $x = x+a$ and then $a$ would have to be equal to $0$ and $x$ could be any value. So now let us assume $b \not = 1$.

As you said you can get it to $x - bx = ab$. Now you can factor the $x$ on the left side to get $x(1-b) = ab$ and then we can divide by $1-b$ (because we supposed $b$ was not equal to $1$ earlier) and get $x = \frac{ab}{1-b}$

Comment: Thank You!  Exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply factor input out of the rhs, getting $x=\frac{ab}{1-b}$, where $x$ is the input?